# Reuse ViewModel materializer in multiple EF queries?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, linq-expressions

I'd like to reuse the method that hydrates a view model from an Entity Framework 6 `IQueryable<TEntity>`. Most intuitively to me, that would look something like this:

```
ViewModel ToViewModel(Record record) {
    return new ViewModel {
        Title = record.Title
    }
}

// Get a single ViewModel
ViewModel GetRecord(int id) {
    return ToViewModel(Context.Records.Find(id));
}

// Get multiple ViewModels
IEnumerable<ViewModel> GetRecords() {
    return
        from record in Context.Records
        select ToViewModel(record);
}
```

Unfortunately EF tries to send the `ToViewModel()` method to the database, so enumerating the query result causes an Exception similar to "this method cannot be translated into a store expression".

Typically I'd prefer not to load the entire `Entity<Record>` (and all related objects referenced in the initializer) over the wire for performance reasons, otherwise I could do the following:

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> GetRecords() {
    return
        from record in Context.Records.ToList()
        select ToViewModel(record);
}
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something fairly simple with `Expression` typing. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you think correctly that you should use Expression. Prepare the method, and a new helper, like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Record, ViewModel>> GetToViewModelExpression() {
    return r => new ViewModel {
        Title = r.Title
    };
}

public static ViewModel ToViewModel(Record record) {
    return GetToViewModelExpression().Compile()(record);
}
```

And use it in your dependent methods like this:

```
// Get a single ViewModel
ViewModel GetRecord(int id) {
    return ToViewModel(Context.Records.Find(id));
}

// Get multiple ViewModels
IEnumerable<ViewModel> GetRecords() {
    return Context
        .Records
        .Select(GetToViewModelExpression());
}
```

Comment: ugh, so more more indirection! but I'll take it! :) Thank you.

Comment: Made some minor adjustments so that it works in both OP cases.

Comment: I should mention that I removed the `Expression<>` wrapper, using a `Func<>` directly in my case, but the resulting code can then have a similar problem nested one level deeper, if the initializer performs additional work. This could also cause EF to fail to select related values automatically; e.g. instead iterating to lazy load many related full entities for single values.

Comment: An alternate solution would be to leave the `Expression<>` return type, but additionally include a method that returns the result of `Expression<>.Compile()(record)`.

Comment: Your code completely changes the way it works!!! With your changes select GetToViewModelFunc is executed in memory of your program, and not in the database. So your query first retrives all Records objects and then in memory of your program takes from them only Title. This is bad for performance as you load a lot of unnecessary data. If you want that your select expression will be part of query sent to db then you have to use Expression. If you use Func it can only be executed in your application. Check it yourself - Select extension method accepting Func return IEnumerable.

Comment: On the contrary Select with Expression parameter returns IQueryable - this means you are still building a query and not working on result of it.

Comment: Calm down. :) Your answer did not fully answer my question, including how to apply the transform to a single Record, so I had to improvise. I could create my own answer if you like ;)

Comment: What kind of transform you have in mind? Is it mention anywhere in your question? You stated in your question that you do not want load entire Record object, but you solution leads to this. If you are ok about performing select logic in memory you just can call ToList() method before select statement and there you can place method invokation like this: Context.Records.ToList().Select(ToViewModel). But this will cause loading all Records data what you wanted to avoid. What additional transformations do you need? :)

Comment: Yes, my question mentioned a need to also hydrate a single instance of the ViewModel, for example following a call to `DbSet.Find` in the OP. That was the major reason I initially edited your solution (incorrectly) to use a delegate rather than expression. I've made another edit, how does it look?

Comment: Yes, it is deffinitely better now, thank you for that edit. Now GetRecords will not load unnecessary data annd on the other hand selecting ViewModel maybe done in memory when only one object is being loaded. I do not better solution at the moment.